# Скрипт для группы checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vbscript

На обычной html страничке есть несколько `checkbox` вида

```
<input id="All" type="checkbox" checked />
<input id="Valid" type="checkbox"  />
<input id="Dissolved" type="checkbox"  />
```

Как сделать так чтобы если выбран один из них остальные были недоступны, желательно на VBScript

И почему когда я пытаюсь проверить выбран или нет, мне возвращается значение вида `Истина\Ложь` вместо `True\False`

```
allContract = document.getElementById("AllContract").Checked
```

Comment: Вы хотите решение в JavaScript или в VBScript? По тегам не понятно.

Comment: Желательно VBScript